# boost::asio async_read doesn't receive data or doesn't use callback

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to receive data from a server application using boost asio's `async_read()` free function, but the callback I set for when the receiving is never called.

The client code is like this:

```
Client::Client()
{
  m_oIoService.run(); // member boost::asio::io_service
  m_pSocket = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(m_oIoService);

  // Connection to the server
  [...]

  // First read
  boost::asio::async_read(*m_pSocket,
                          boost::asio::buffer((void*)&m_oData, sizeof(m_oData)),
                          boost::bind(&Client::handleReceivedData, this,
                                      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

I tried with small data (a short string) and I can't get it to work. When I use the synchronous read function (`boost::asio::read()`) using the two same first parameters, everything works perfectly.

Am I missing something with the use of the io_service? I am still unsure about how it works.

Comment: You're calling io_service::run without any events it'll return and then you queue the async_read but the io_service isn't running, just move the call to run to the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`boost::asio::service::run ()` is a blocking call. Now, in your example it may or may not return immediately. In case it doesn't, you you are blocked even before you create a socket, and never call read, so cannot expect a callback. Otherwise, dispatch loop is exited, so no callbacks are ever delivered.

Read more about [`boost::asio::service::run ()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html). I recommend you check out [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio.html) including tutorial, examples and reference. It is worth going trough it in full to understand the concept.

Hope it helps!

P.S.: On a side note, your code is not exception safe. Beware that if constructor of the class fails with exception then destructor of that class instance is never called. Thus, you may leak at least `m_pSocket` if its type is not one of the "smart pointers". You should consider making it exception safe, moving the code to another method that should be called by user, or even wrapping this functionality with a free function.

Comment: +1 this is an important concept to understand when using Boost.Asio. You need to ensure the `io_service` has some work to do prior to invoking `io_service::run()`.

Comment: +1 for advice to read the docs and the tutorials.  Just about everything you need is in there.

Comment: Thanks, I moved the call to run() after the call to async_read and it works now. I'm pretty sure I tried this before but I might have made another mistake at that time. If I understood correctly, the callback qlso needs to call async_read before it returns so the io_service doesn't stop. As for the exception safety, the code isn't exactly like this in reality, I just summarized several functions in order to make it shorter and easily readable.